# passing ng-model variable to an ng-click function

Tags: angularjs

in my case I generate "recent searches" links getting the anchor text from a list (ng-repeat="city in meteo.cityList").
Then I want to call a function passing the content of the ancor text, so I'm trying to use ng-model (ng-model='meteo.button') to get the value and ng-click to call the function (ng-click="meteo.search(meteo.button)")

```
<nav class="recent-cities">   
    <h3>Search History:</h3>

      <a ng-repeat="city in meteo.cityList" ng-model='meteo.button'  ng-click="meteo.search(meteo.button)"  href="#">{{city}}</a>

 </nav>
```

It doesn't work because ng-model does't get the value. I also wanted to pass "city" directly to the function but it doesn't work.
I guess the issue is about rendering but i can't figure out how.

Here is the entire code: http://codepen.io/tiuscia/pen/qqLQNd

I will appreciate any kind of help

thanks

Answer (score 2):

use a div first

```
<div ng-repeat="city in meteo.cityList">
<a ng-model='city.button'  ng-click="meteo.search(city.button)"  href="#">{{city}}</a>
```

Comment: Hi thank for your reply.
I tried to put a div but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: I guess the value that u r trying to pass is in json format

Comment: the function works with the text input, i get xml data and then I convert them in json. The function search() has an optional input. It works with ng-click, but ng-model can't pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is using `$event` to retrieve the clicked element, so:

```
<a ng-model='city.button'  
   ng-click="meteo.search($event)"  href="#">{{city}}</a>
```

Then you can do something like this in your controller function:

```
$scope.meteo.search = function(event) {
  var city = event.target.text; // or event.currentTarget.text
  // the rest of your code here...
```

another way is creating you own custom directive, so, you pass the city name (or city.button) to the directive.

Comment: Hi, I'd like to use only one function, because the text  input and the recent links do the same. The function in ng-click works but the problem is the input, it seems like the function can't get the ng-model value.

Comment: I guess the problem is how I set up the function parameter. I want it optional but i did it in the wrong way